# What's the reference block for the billing in Paypal Express review?

Tags: layout, blocks, template, paypal-express, customer-address

I could have sworn that I had this but now I can't seem to get the correct reference block for the billing address in paypal express review. My module's layout.xml is:

```
...
<paypal_express_review>
    <reference name="paypal.express.review.address">
         <action method="setTemplate">
              <template>new_layout/address.phtml</template>
         </action>
    </reference>
</paypal_express_review>
...
```

I'm obviously looking to overwrite the default one. It looks as if it should be "paypal.express.review.address" but it's not. I must have tried 50 combos. Anyone got this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to use `express.review.billing` or `express.review.shipping`. It will change on which address template you want to change.

See the following extract from `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/paypal.xml`

```
<paypal_express_review translate="label">
    <label>PayPal Express Order Review Form</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="paypal/express_review" name="paypal.express.review" template="paypal/express/review.phtml">
            <block type="paypal/express_review_billing" name="express.review.billing" as="billing" template="paypal/express/review/address.phtml"/>
            <block type="paypal/express_review_shipping" name="express.review.shipping" as="shipping" template="paypal/express/review/address.phtml"/>
            <block type="paypal/express_review" name="express.review.shipping.method" as="shipping_method" template="paypal/express/review/shipping/method.phtml"/>
            <block type="paypal/express_review_details" name="paypal.express.review.details" as="details" template="paypal/express/review/details.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="paypal.express.review.details.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/agreements" name="paypal.express.review.details.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/checkout/review.js</name></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</paypal_express_review>
```

Comment: + Top work David! So does that mean to get the reference name of any block (and in this case override the template) you should locate the relevant layout file and use the block name as stated?_

Comment: When ever I am looking to change the layout I always check what the block has set for the name in layout. Though there are some blocks added to pages not via the layout.xml most are.